# Clearing all cookies in Watir Webdriver

Tags: cucumber, watir-webdriver

In order to make my test run faster I decided to open and close browser only once. With clearing cookies between scenarios.

Alister Scott described it here http://watirmelon.com/2012/04/01/five-page-object-anti-patterns/

hooks.rb:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

Before do
  @browser = browser
end

at_exit do
  browser.close
end

After do
  @browser.cookies.clear
end
```

But the problem is that some tests checking the redirection to `anothersite.com`, so `@browser.cookies.clear` clearing cookies only for the `anothersite.com`. How do I really clear **all** cookies without closing the browser?

At this time I temporarily (I hope so) add

```
After('@sometag') do
  @browser.goto 'mysite.com'
  @browser.cookies.clear
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cookies on the main browser object and not the copy of it you are working with. so `@browser.cookies.clear` becomes `browser.cookies.clear`. I got a feeling that will solve your problem.

Comment: I have done ```browser.cookies.clear``` at after do hook. But it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: If you know the name of the cookie you can try deleting it explicitly `browser.cookies.delete 'my_session'`. Or if it is a specific attribute in the cookie you could try juts deleting that.